# Logo too big when using 100% width

Tags: html, css

If I lower the width, the logo will be affected in smaller screen sizes so it needs to take 100%.

But if I use 100% width then the logo is too big.

I tried making the picture smaller but it's still the same size when I use 100% width.

I've been dealing with this issue for an entire year, trying to figure it out myself. What do I do?

```
<img class="logo" src="logo.png">



logo {
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    top: -15px;
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
 }
```

Comment: add a `max-width`

Answer (score 1):

You should use MediaQuery

```css
#logo {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 468px) {
  #logo {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" id="logo" />
```

or use `min-width` and `max-width` like the following:

```css
#logo {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" id="logo" />
```

[Read more about css media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
img {
    display: block;
    max-width:100px;
    max-height:100px;

    height: auto;
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    top: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<img width="400" height="400" src="https://ffp4g1ylyit3jdyti1hqcvtb-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/firefox/files/2017/12/firefox-logo-300x310.png">
```